# AngularJS: Where does code belong that updates a form field after a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, separation-of-concerns, angularjs-design-patterns

In my AngularJS app, I have a template that contains a `<textarea>` and a submit button. A `<div>` (which could just as easily be a `<form>`) wraps both of those elements and has a controller. The controller utilizes a [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service to `POST` the value from the `<textarea>` to a REST API when the submit button is clicked.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <textarea ng-model="vm.text" rows="5"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="vm.save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['myRestApiResource'];

function MyController(myRestApiResource) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.save = function() {
    var params = [];
    var postData = {text: vm.text};
    myRestApiResource.save(params, postData)
      .then(function(res) { /* success handler */ })
      .catch(function(res) { /* error handler */ });
  };
}
```

When the resource `save()` method's [$promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) is rejected, the response data (in some cases) contains an `error.position` property that refers to the string index where a syntax error was detected in `vm.text`.

In those cases, I focus on the `<textarea>` element and [set the selection range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) from the `error.position` to the next non-word character. I have a function for this, and it all works fine.

My question is:

Should the function call that sets the selection range on the `<textarea>` (after the promise is rejected) be performed in...

1. the controller
2. a custom directive added to the textarea
3. somewhere else

...and why?

This is a question about **separation of concerns**.

The controller seems like the most sensible place, but it is my understanding that controllers should not perform DOM manipulation...and this would require the use of the `$element` service (or jQuery) for doing just that.

A custom directive would need to subscribe to an event broadcast by the controller, and then set its own focus and selection range. This separates the concerns, but according to [Angular Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices) `$broadcast` and `$on` should only be used for "events that are relevant globally across the entire app".

I suppose the controller and directive could communicate via another service, but that just seems like over-engineering -- something I am notorious for and trying hard to avoid here! :-)

Thanks in advance!

---

### Solution

For completeness, here is the custom directive I wrote based on @kristin-fritsch 's answer:

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('selectionRange', selectionRangeDirective);

function selectionRangeDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      selectionRange: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement) {
      var element = iElement[0];
      if (element.setSelectionRange && typeof element.setSelectionRange === 'function') {
        scope.$watch('selectionRange', function(range) {
          if (range && typeof range.start === 'number' && range.start > -1 && range.start < iElement.val().length) {
            element.focus();
            element.setSelectionRange(range.start, range.end);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
}
```

To implement it, I added the directive attribute to my textarea:

```
<textarea ng-model="vm.text" rows="5" selection-range="vm.selection"></textarea>
```

...and set the value of `vm.selection` to an object with `start` and `end` properties in my controller, when the promise is rejected.

```
myRestApiResource.save(params, postData)
  .then(function(res) { /* success handler */ })
  .catch(function(res) {
    var error = res.data.error;
    if (error && error.position) {
      var start = error.position;
      var end = start + vm.text.substr(start).search(/(\W|$)/);
      vm.selection = {start: start, end: end};
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you add a directive to the textarea.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <textarea ng-model="vm.text" data-error-position="errorPosition" rows="5"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="vm.save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Then you could set the position when the $promise got rejected like this

```
$scope.errorPosition = 50;
```

And handle the DOM manipulation in the errorPosition - directive.